# Convert Postman call into normal API call

Tags: rest, postman, outsystems

I'm currently making use of an API from [Free OCR API](https://ocr.space/ocrapi) (using the POST call). I've tried it using Postman, and it seems to work fine. But when I use it through Outsystems, I get an Internal server error. The requests created by both services are pretty much the same, but it doesn't work through anything other than Postman.

Here are the Request call made:

Postman call:

```
POST /parse/image HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ocr.space
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3e58eea7-4108-dd26-e79b-1183ee6e5908
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="apikey"

404f8bdbfe88957
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language"

eng
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="base64image"

data:image/bmp;base64,<base64 text>
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Outsystems call:

```
POST /parse/image HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu088
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: api.ocr.space
User-Agent: OutSystemsPlatform

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="apikey"

404f8bdbfe88957
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language"

eng
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="base64image"

data:image/bmp;base64,<base64 text>
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu088--
```

Does Postman do anything additional that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to generate this multipart req too? It might shed a little light.

Comment: @PhilSturgeon I copied the multipart req body from the Postman call.

Comment: Did you post here all the request made from OutSystems? I'm missing the Postman-Token... I guess that's an auth token...

Comment: @PedroCardoso I did. The same for me. Postman-Toekn is missing.

Comment: The token is a header. Did you included it in the call?

Comment: No I did not. The Postman token is auto created by the Postman API client. I don't know how to generate it outside of Postman.